# Inserting data dynamically in Temporary table by Select Statement only

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, temp-tables, sp-executesql

I want to insert dynamic record in temporary table. 
I don't want to declare this table. I want its columns to be defined at run time. 
I am doing this because definition of table "Contract" may change in future. So temporary table(#x) should be changed accordingly. And this will be in a Stored Procedure.

I have tried following ways(which were marked as answers, none works though)

```
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    'SELECT top 1 * FROM Contract'
      INTO #x
    select * from #x
```

---

```
    declare @arj varchar(100)
    set @arj= 'SELECT top 1 * FROM Contract'
    select * into #x from 
    (SELECT top 1 * FROM Contract)
```

---

```
    declare @arj varchar(100)
    set @arj= 'SELECT top 1 * FROM Contract'
    SELECT * into #x execute ('execute' + 
    --and this-- SELECT into #T1 execute ('execute ' + @SQLString ) @arj  )
    SELECT *from #x
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This syntax should work but you need to create the sql dynamically and then execute it:

```
 SELECT top 1  * 
 INTO #x
 FROM Contract
```

Example:

```
  SELECT TOP 0 * INTO #x from Contract 

  DECLARE @ARJ NVARCHAR(MAX)
  SET @ARJ='INSERT INTO #x SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Contract'
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @ARJ
```

Comment: Hi Jayvee,

I get following message.

`(1 row(s) affected)`
`Invalid object name '#x'.`

So it's not working for me.

Comment: I've edited to use ##x instead of #x. Please try it now.

Comment: It works but that I cannot use. No global temp tables.

Comment: The only work around in that case is to create the temp table before the sp and then insert into it. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you Jayvee. However I get this error


`An explicit value for the identity column in table '#x' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.`

But now I know what to do. Thanks. You gave me the direction to head.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT top 1 * INTO #tempTable FROM Contract WHERE <any conditions you might want to filter the data>
```

Comment: Hi Jayachandran,
Actually my original query is pretty longer than this. The one I have mentioned is for reference. So it has to be in a variable. So, this one's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *  
INTO #tempTable
from Contract  
WHERE 1=0
```

I Use this query to build a table with all the field of Contract table and the same properties. Hope it helps.

Comment: My real query is longer than this. This variable @arj is for reference.

Comment: I have long queries too instead of Contract use that ever you have in your query after FROM .

Comment: No sir, it's better if we keep @arj in the game.

Answer (score 0):

this syntax should work.

```
declare @arj varchar(1000)
set @arj= 'SELECT top 1 * FROM Contract'
declare @charIdex int   
declare @arg2 varchar(1000)


SELECT @charIdex =  CHARINDEX ( 'FROM',
       @arj)
   SELECT @arg2 = STUFF(@arj, @charIdex, 0 , 'into tempTable ');
 exec   ( @arg2)
 select * from tempTable
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but with this i get this error `Invalid object name '#tempTable'.`

Comment: Just the same error I got for the other solutions i mentioned in my questions.